# is there any way to convert mediaStream to blob without using MediaRecorder?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, webrtc

recently I had a problem with iOS 11, I want to capture a video from user but media recorder api is not implemented on iOS 11, do you know any alternative for mediaRecorder to convert mediaStream to blob ?